# Can I somehow work around this particular aspect of ResourceIterator's laziness?

Tags: java, concurrency, neo4j

When there are two concurrent transactions `t1` and `t2` (I'll skip boilerplate, just assume that I'm doing everything by the book):

Thread A : `t1`:

```
it1 = db.findNodes(label);
it1.forEach(node -> println(node.hasLabel(label))
```

Thread B : `t2`:

```
it2 = db.findNodes(label);
it2.forEach(node -> node.removeLabel(label))
```

Now, from my point of view, we have a *huge* inconsistency here: if thread A executes slower than thread B, at the point we check if the node in A has a label `label`, the result will be `false`!

As a developer, I understand that since iterators are lazy, this is kind of predictable and I see the reason behind this behaviour, but as an API user, I was really annoyed with the fact that I can't be 100% sure that the nodes that I requested as those having *the* `label`, turn out not to have it!

Also, there might be a situation where it's not possible to obtain a write lock on any entity that will guard all those nodes from concurrent modification, hence I can't have consistency even with some fine tools.

I really don't think that this is a bug - rather a feature gone wild. However, I would be really glad to know if there is any solution that will help me with my issue.

Update: here's how this pseudo-race condition happens:

```
Before: create 100 nodes with :Label
A: get iterator for all nodes with :Label
B: get iterator for all nodes with :Label
A: consume e.g. 50 nodes
B: remove labels from all nodes, commit
A: see the rest of the nodes as the ones not having :Label
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a tough question there - since no one has attempted an answer, I'll attempt one.

I think the answer is wrapped up in the details of how neo4j deals with transactions.  [This particular link dealing with transaction isolation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-isolation.html) seems very relevant to me, which says:

> Transactions in Neo4j use a read-committed isolation level, which
>   means they will see data as soon as it has been committed and will not
>   see data in other transactions that have not yet been committed. This
>   type of isolation is weaker than serialization but offers significant
>   performance advantages whilst being sufficient for the overwhelming
>   majority of cases.

I take for granted that you removing those labels is happening within a transaction.  My read says that not a single label in Thread A can change, until all of Thread B has finished.  This is because you might remove labels from many nodes, but none of that is real/visible to any other thread until the removal transaction commits.  At least this is how it should be.

So your race condition here is when Thread A starts *while* Thread B is executing, but *before* Thread B commits.

I think your best answer probably comes from the second paragraph of that link:

> In addition, the Neo4j Java API (see Advanced Usage) enables explicit
>   locking of nodes and relationships. Using locks gives the opportunity
>   to simulate the effects of higher levels of isolation by obtaining and
>   releasing locks explicitly. For example, if a write lock is taken on a
>   common node or relationship, then all transactions will serialize on
>   that lock — giving the effect of a serialization isolation level.

Inside of Thread B, you might want to [acquire a read lock](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#acquireReadLock%28org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer%29) on the nodes that you're modifying.  That lock would be released when the transaction commits.

I'm not 100% sure of this answer, but I think it makes sense.  If someone more experienced can improve on this or contradict, please jump in.

Comment: I'm familiar with both links you've provided, but, as I mentioned, in case of a large number of nodes (or if they are densely connected) it's impractical to lock on them all since that means locking on a large number of (possibly) other nodes. As about race condition - I'll update my post with some kind of a diagram to make my point more clear, please have a look later.